# Select top and/or bottom face of bmesh cone

Tags: python, faces, bmesh

I would like to ask if there is a better way to select the bottom and top face of a cone then how I do it now

```
bmesh.ops.create_cone(
bm, 
cap_ends=True, 
cap_tris=False, 
segments=32,  #<-- this one has a slider that will in or decrease the numbers of segments 
diameter1=(1), 
diameter2=(1), 
depth=1  
)
```

The code below fails as soon as you have 4 or less segments

```
caps = [f for f in bm.faces if len(f.verts) > 4]
bottom_cap = min(caps, key=lambda f: f.verts[0].co.z)
top_cap = max(caps, key=lambda f: f.verts[0].co.z)
```

Comment: Create the cone without caps.  Find the boundary edge loops.  close each edge loop with a face and remember that face.

Answer (score 2):

Likely you can investigate the order of vertices and how it correlates with the base(s) of the cylinder/cone. However, you're not guaranteed this order won't be changed in next versions of Blender.

Here's a solution that checks face normals to establish which are the bases:

```py
import bpy, bmesh
from bpy import context as C

me = C.active_object.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

verts = bmesh.ops.create_cone(
bm, 
cap_ends=True, 
cap_tris=False, 
segments=32,
diameter1=(1), 
diameter2=(1), 
depth=1  
)['verts']

bases = {f for v in verts for f in v.link_faces if abs(f.normal.z) == 1}
for b in bases:
    b.select = True

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```

Comment: Thanks @Markus von Broady.

May I ask how select only top or bottom? I need them in separate var.

Comment: @cecevo top has positive `normal.z`, bottom has it negative (that's why I use `abs` to make both the same)